# Determine processor support for SSE2?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, sse2

I need to do determine processor support for SSE2 prior installing a software. From what I understand, I came up with this:

```
bool TestSSE2(char * szErrorMsg)
{
    __try 
    {
        __asm 
        {
              xorpd xmm0, xmm0        // executing SSE2 instruction
        }
    }
        #pragma warning (suppress: 6320)
        __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) 
        {
            if (_exception_code() == STATUS_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION) 
            {
                _tcscpy_s(szErrorMsg,MSGSIZE, _T("Streaming SIMD Extensions 2(SSE2) is not supported by the CPU.\r\n Unable to launch APP"));
                return false;

            }
        _tcscpy_s(szErrorMsg,MSGSIZE, _T("Streaming SIMD Extensions 2(SSE2) is not supported by the CPU.\r\n Unable to launch APP"));
        return false;
        }   
    return true;
}
```

Would this work?  I'm not really sure how to test, since my CPU supports it, so I don't get false from the function call.

How do I determine processor support for SSE2?

Comment: Any particular operating system ?

Comment: Your code should work fine as far as I can tell. I'd prefer the CPUID way because it's a bit more flexible and gives you access to a whole bunch of other CPU capability flags as well.

Comment: You could run a virtualized OS, and have it emulate a non-SSE2 CPU.  It might not be fast, but it should be accurate, no?

Comment: Processor support and OS support for SSE2 are two different things. The processor may support SSE2 so the proper bit is set after CPUID. However, the OS may ***not*** have enabled it (I think it needs to enable MMX extensions). For CPU support, Ashley provided the answer. For OS support under Windows, Timbo provided the answer. I have not seen the answer for OS support under Linux. I *think* these are GCC tests for SSE2 OS support: [sse-6.c source file](ftp://ftp.tku.edu.tw/NetBSD/NetBSD-release-6/src/external/gpl3/gcc/dist/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/i386/sse-6.c).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call CPUID with eax = 1 to load the feature flags in to edx.  Bit 26 is set if SSE2 is available.  Some code for demonstration purposes, using MSVC++ inline assembly (only for x86 and not portable!):

```
inline unsigned int get_cpu_feature_flags()
{
    unsigned int features;

    __asm
    {
        // Save registers
        push    eax
        push    ebx
        push    ecx
        push    edx

        // Get the feature flags (eax=1) from edx
        mov     eax, 1
        cpuid
        mov     features, edx

        // Restore registers
        pop     edx
        pop     ecx
        pop     ebx
        pop     eax
    }

    return features;
}

// Bit 26 for SSE2 support
static const bool cpu_supports_sse2 = (cpu_feature_flags & 0x04000000)!=0;
```

Comment: You should better use the __cpuid intrinsic, because inline assembly is no longer supported by the Microsoft AMD64 compiler.

Comment: Is there a guide on what to check at compilation time to know what SSE instruction sets a processor has available? SSE3, SSE4, SSE4.1 etc...

Answer (score 17):

I found this one by accident in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724482(VS.85).aspx):

```
BOOL sse2supported = ::IsProcessorFeaturePresent( PF_XMMI64_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE );
```

Windows-only, but if you are not interested in anything cross-platform, very simple.

Answer (score 10):

The most basic way to check for SSE2 support is by using the `CPUID` instruction (on platforms where it is available). Either using inline assembly or using compiler intrinsics.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the _cpuid function. All is explained in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6aek1h%28VS.80%29.aspx).